# Añadir marcos de datos uno tras otro

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Tengo quatros marco de datos de un archivo csv que descargué [aquí](https://www.lendingclub.com/info/download-data.action) (préstamos bancarios del año 2018. Se dividen en cuatro trimestres). [Gracias a FJSevilla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/279418/2633) los descargué de esta manera:

```
data_Q1 = pd.read_csv("LoanStats_2018Q1.csv", skiprows=1, skipfooter=2, engine='python')
data_Q2 = pd.read_csv("LoanStats_2018Q2.csv", skiprows=1, skipfooter=2, engine='python')
data_Q3 = pd.read_csv("LoanStats_2018Q2.csv", skiprows=1, skipfooter=2, engine='python')
data_Q4 = pd.read_csv("LoanStats_2018Q2.csv", skiprows=1, skipfooter=2, engine='python')
```

Sin embargo, necesito saber el número total de préstamos, el recuento de datos faltantes para cada una de esta columna y el número de préstamos que todavía están vigentes en el conjunto de la historia.

Para hacer eso, pensé en añadir marcos de datos uno tras otro, pero ¿cómo?

Por lo momento intenté:

```
data = data_Q1.append(data_Q2,data_Q3,data_Q4)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-73c914f8ebaa> in <module>
----> 1 data = data_Q1.append(data_Q2,data_Q3,data_Q4)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in append(self, other, ignore_index, verify_integrity, sort)
   6209         return concat(to_concat, ignore_index=ignore_index,
   6210                       verify_integrity=verify_integrity,
-> 6211                       sort=sort)
   6212 
   6213     def join(self, other, on=None, how='left', lsuffix='', rsuffix='',

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in concat(objs, axis, join, join_axes, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
    223                        keys=keys, levels=levels, names=names,
    224                        verify_integrity=verify_integrity,
--> 225                        copy=copy, sort=sort)
    226     return op.get_result()
    227 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in __init__(self, objs, axis, join, join_axes, keys, levels, names, ignore_index, verify_integrity, copy, sort)
    376         self.copy = copy
    377 
--> 378         self.new_axes = self._get_new_axes()
    379 
    380     def get_result(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in _get_new_axes(self)
    456                 new_axes[i] = ax
    457 
--> 458         new_axes[self.axis] = self._get_concat_axis()
    459         return new_axes
    460 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in _get_concat_axis(self)
    504             indexes = [x._data.axes[self.axis] for x in self.objs]
    505 
--> 506         if self.ignore_index:
    507             idx = com._default_index(sum(len(i) for i in indexes))
    508             return idx

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1574         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
   1575                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
-> 1576                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
   1577 
   1578     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Si tienes métodos más simples estoy escuchando.

Comment: ¿`concat`? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: @abulafia Exactamente